# php mysql count

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table that logs how many of an item people have, table is set up like

```
Name        Item          Amount
--------------------------------
Knob        Pistol          5
Knee        Pistol          2
Hat         Shotgun         3
```

I want to loop through the table and find out the total number of certain items. So if i searched for 'Pistol', it would output 7.

Do I have to loop through each record and add them to a number count, or is there a quicker way of doing it?

Comment: Did you tried SUM with GROUP BY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic SQL question. You really should look at the SQL docs to learn more. The function you're looking for is SUM.

```
    SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM table WHERE item = 'Pistol'
```

This would return

```
    total
    -------------
    7
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT Sum(Amount) FROM table_name WHERE Item = 'Pistol'
```